# Import multiple CSV files into database once uploaded in a directory

Tags: csv, sftp, batch-processing, inotify

I need some feedbacks regarding the right way to execute a command that import a CSV content into a mysql database according to this scenario:

A CSV file contains a **single** order.

Once an order is complete, the CSV is uploaded via sFTP to my server. It may occurs that multiple CSVs could be uploaded within a minute.

The command will:

1. fetch all CSV files in a specific directory
2. parse each one
3. make a simple `INSERT` SQL query
4. delete the file if the query is successful or move the file in the case of any exception thrown

I thought about 2 solutions:

- a cron task that runs a command every 15 minutes
- use `inotify-tools` library

Regarding the second solution, I have some doubts in the case where I execute my command every time a file is created in the folder. Imagine there are multiple uploaded files with a very short interval. Don't you think some conflicts may appear while the command is running ?

What do you think ?

Here is the symfony command:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use AppBundle\Model\Entity\Consts\DeliveryNoteFlowOrigin;
use AppBundle\Model\Entity\Consts\DeliveryNoteStatus;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException;
use League\Csv\Reader;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo;

class ImportCsvCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * @var Connection
     */
    private $dbal;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uploadCsv;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $backupCsv;

    public function __construct(
        Connection $dbal,
        string $uploadCsv,
        string $backupCsv
    ) {
        $this->dbal = $dbal;
        $this->uploadCsv = $uploadCsv;
        $this->backupCsv = $backupCsv;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:store:csv')
            ->setDescription('Create delivery notes from CSV.')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $io->title('Attempting import of  CSV files...');

        $finder = new Finder();

        $finder->files()->name('*.csv')->in($this->uploadCsv);

        // Warning: If your CSV document is read on a Macintosh computer,
        // add the following lines before using the library to help PHP detect line ending.
        // (\r line endings are created by Microsoft Excel when saving as a CSV file)
        if (!ini_get('auto_detect_line_endings')) {
            ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', '1');
        }

        foreach ($finder as $file) {
            $csv = Reader::createFromPath($file->getRealPath())
                ->setHeaderOffset(0)
            ;

            // TODO check memory leak
            foreach ($csv as $order) {
                dump($order);
                die();

                try {
                    $this->importDeliveryNote($file, $order);
                } catch (PDOException $PDOException) {
                    // TODO log
                } catch (IOExceptionInterface $IOException) {
                    // TODO log
                } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                    // TODO log
                }
            }
        }

        $io->success('Command exited cleanly!');
    }

    private function importDeliveryNote(SplFileInfo $file, array $order): void
    {
        $fileSystem = new Filesystem();

        $filename = $file->getFilename();
        $fileRealPath = $file->getRealPath();
        $now = (new \DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $sth = $this->dbal->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO delivery_note (status, seller_name, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (:status, :sellerName, :firstname, :lastname, :email)'
        );

        //Do not forget to validate your data before inserting it in your database
        $sth->bindValue(':status', $order['TODO'], DeliveryNoteStatus::PREPARED);
        $sth->bindValue(':sellerName', $order['TODO'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':firstname', $order['TODO'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':lastname', $order['TODO'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':email', $order['TODO'], \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $queryHasBeenSuccessful = $sth->execute();

        if ($queryHasBeenSuccessful) {
            $fileSystem->remove($fileRealPath);
        } else {
            // Move to backup directory
            $newPathname = $this->backupCsv.$filename;

            if (!$fileSystem->exists($newPathname)) {
                $fileSystem->rename($file->getPathname(), $newPathname);
            }
        }
    }
}
```